# AttributeError in Python: Using input from one function in another

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have this code that I'm working on in Python but when I'm trying to use the input (date) from visit_info in opening_hours I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'date'`

The assignment is to create a program for a zoo where the user can type what date they want to visit and gets the opening hours for the zoo. After that they should type in what time of the day they want to visit and the program is supposed to answer by printing information about the animals that can be seen during the visit (depending on if they are awake or not). I'm a beginner so I have no idea what I'm doing but this is all of my (extremely messy) code:

from time import *

nu = localtime()

print(nu)

animal_dict = {}

class Visit:

```
'''
Class for the visit
'''
def __init__(self, date, time_arrival, time_departure):
    '''
    creates new visit
    :param date: date for visit
    :param time_arrival: time for arrival
    :param time_departure: time for departure
    Time is written in whole hours
    '''

    self.date = date
    self.time_arrival = time_arrival
    self.time_departure = time_departure

def __str__(self):
    """
    Visit information for printouts
    :return: A string including date and time for visit
    """

    return "\nDate: " + self.date + "\nTime: "+ str(self.time_arrival) + "-" + str(self.time_departure)

def opening_hours(self, user_input):
    '''
    Compare month and date of visit with the opening hours for the zoo
    :param month: month of visit
    :param date: date of visit
    :return:
    '''


    import datetime

    user_input = list(map(int, user_input.split('-')))
    day = datetime.date(user_input[0], user_input[1], user_input[2])
    print(day.weekday())

    if weekday == 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:
        print("The zoo is open from 14-20")
    else:
        print("The zoo is open from 10-22")

    return

def compare_time(self, an_dict):
    '''
    Compare time of visit with the time the animals are awake. Uses input from user and a dictionary with the animals
    :param time_arrival: time of arrival
    :param time_departure: time of departure
    :param animal_dict: dictionary with animals and their attributes
    :return: attributes of animals
    '''


    wake_up_time = an_dict[2]
    sleep_time = an_dict[3]

    if (wake_up_time >= time_arrival) or (sleep_time <= time_departure):
        pass
    return

def compare_months(self, animal_dict, month, winter_months):
    '''
    Check if any animals hibernate.
    :param month: Month of visit
    :param winter_months: list with winter months
    :return: attributes of relevant animals
    '''

    pass
```

def winter():

```
'''
Define what months are winter time
:return: List with months that are winter time
'''

winter = ["november", "december", "january", "february", "march",
          "November", "December", "January", "February", "March"]

return winter
```

def read_animals_from_file(file_name):

```
'''
Makes a dictionary with the animals as keys and their attributes as values
:param file_name: Name of the file with information
:return: Dictionary with the animals and their attributes
'''

import pprint

fobj = open(file_name, "r")
for line in fobj:
    key , value1 , value2 , value3 , value4 = line.split("/")
    animal_dict[key] = value1, int(value2), int(value3), int(value4)

print(animal_dict)
return animal_dict
```

def print_relevant_animals():

```
'''
Use compare_time and compare_months to decide what animals will be printed
:return: string with information about the animals
'''
pass
```

def visit_info():

```
'''
When do you want to visit?
Gets input
The zoo is open xx-xx
Time of arrival?
Time of departure?
:param date: Date of visit
:param time_arrival: Time of arrival
:param time_departure: Time of departure
:return: Return information that was asked for
'''

date = input("Date for visit (yyyy-mm-dd): ")

Visit()

time_arrival = input("Time of arrival (whole hour): ")
time_departure = input("Time of departure (whole hour): ")

your_visit = Visit(month, date, time_arrival, time_departure)

print("Your visit: " + your_visit.__str__())

return your_visit, date, time_arrival, time_departure
```

read_animals_from_file("animals_on_zoo.txt")

visit_info()

I also have a text file with information about the animals on the format: type_of_animal / hibernation / wake_up_time / sleep_time / feeding_time

I'm not sure how to use date from visit_info in opening_hours.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough code here for me to run it and try some things. Nevertheless, have you tried using a global variable? You could also use a return value, depending on how/where you're calling the functions. I'd like to see the full example of your code that generates the error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand exactly what you're looking to do, but I think you need something closer to this to access the properties of the Visit class instance:

```
class Visit(object):
    def __init__(self, date, time_arrival, time_departure):


        self.date = date
        self.time_arrival = time_arrival
        self.time_departure = time_departure

    def opening_hours(self):
        '''
        Compare month and date of visit with the opening hours for the zoo
        :param month: month of visit
        :param date: date of visit
        :return:
        '''
        import datetime

        userInput = self.date
        userInput = list(map(int, userInput.split('-')))
        day = datetime.date(userInput[0], userInput[1], userInput[2])
        print(day.weekday())

        if day.weekday() in [0,1,2,3,4]:
            print("The zoo is open from 14-20")
        else:
            print("The zoo is open from 10-20")

def visit_info():

    date = input("Date for visit (yyyy-mm-dd): ")
    your_visit = Visit(date, time_arrival=0, time_departure=0)
    your_visit.opening_hours()

    your_visit.time_arrival = input("Time of arrival (whole hour): ")
    your_visit.time_departure = input("Time of departure (whole hour): ")

    return your_visit, date, time_arrival, time_departure

your_visit, date, time_arrival, time_departure = visit_info()
```

Comment: importing a module inside a method definition is bad style

Comment: Absolutely. I just didn't want to change too much in the original code, there's already several changes.

Comment: thank you, this helped a lot! I'm a beginner so I have no idea what I'm doing lol. I also changed where I'm importing the module, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

According to your short code no-one be sure what will be the best solution for this problem.

> But you can Try This, Try this and let me know if it solves problem. Otherwise will find another solution

In your visit_info() Function:

Remove this Line

```
Visit.opening_hours(date)
```

And Add this Line

```
your_visit = Visit(month, date, time_arrival, time_departure)
your_visit.opening_hours()   # >>>> Addition is Here
```